# Evil twin access point with WPA/WPA2

Tags: network, wifi, kali-linux, wpa2, wpa2-psk

When I created an evil twin AP with an SSID of someone else's Wi-Fi network e.g. `MyWifiNet`, I could see two APs on my phone/laptop with the SSID `MyWiFiNet`, however the legitimate one was secured with WPA2 and the evil one was unsecured.

Can I create an evil twin access point with WPA/WPA2 encryption in such a way that when a victim connects with a wrong PSK my evil twin access points accepts this wrong PSK and authenticates the victim as a regular client?

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: hi tester125 - please edit your answer to clarify what it is you are asking, and make sure it meets the guidelines in [ask]

Comment: Even if it gets reopened, which I voted for, it already has an [answer here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/110964/86652).

Answer (score 1):

When you create an Evil Twin wireless network, as you said, if you are "clonning" an unsecured network (network without any encryption) you'll have no problems and the clients will connect to your network instead of legitimate if you enough power to trick them.

If you want to clone a network with any encryption security you must previously know the key to create it in exactly the same way. So a work must be done previously in order to get that password. If no, the clients will never connect automatically to your rogue network.

So, to answer your question... the answer is yes only if you have previously hacked the network to know the exactly parameters including the key. If no, there is no other way.

You can perform DoS to the legitimate network and probably some clients will enter manually into your fake network but of course they must "bite the lure" which is a small part of social engineering.